# Scala implicit classes for generic

Tags: scala, generics, intellij-idea

I'm trying write implicit class for generic class, but build failed with error

> error: value *myMethod* is not a member of *table*

Here is my code

```
implicit class BaseExtensions[E <: WithKey[K], K, T <: MyBaseTable[E,K]](t: TableFactory[T]) { 
  def myMethod = ...
}

trait WithKey[T] { 
  type MyType = T
  ...
}

abstract class MyBaseTable[E <: WithKey[M], M] {
  ... 
}    

class MyTable[...] extends MyBaseTable [...] {
  ...
}
...

val table = TableFactory[MyTable]
val result = table.myMethod
```

What's wrong i do?
PS: Code completion in the IntelliJ IDEA show myMethod as a accessible

Comment: What is `TableFactory`?

Comment: TableFactory is object and trait from a third-party library

Comment: Is the implicit class BaseExtensions defined inside something?  http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html#restrictions

Comment: Yes, class BaseExtensions implemented in package object